# How to take input from UITextField and put it into and add a TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to get my `UITextField` to add the text that is typed to add a cell in a tabel view that uses the text from the `UITextField` as the label of the cell and when you click done in the `UITextField` it adds a new `Cell` with the text as the label that was entered.

How will I go about doing this?

I just have a `UITableView` added into my project without doing anything programmatically.

Comment: are you able add textfield at a cell in UITableView

Comment: You should post some code of what you are trying. It will more accurate to answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Make a array in .h file and initilize it in viewDidLoad and then do it

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textArray addObject:textField];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [textArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // --------- do struff here ---------
}
```

I hope it may help you.....And best of luck..

Comment: You have to reload tableview after adding the data to array.

Comment: I get a "Use of undeclared identifier 'textFieldDidEndEditing' error when using this code. What is making this pop up?

Comment: I think you are getting this error somewhere else not in this method.

Comment: What if I use a NSMutableString/

Comment: May be. You know this is a method so i can't give this error like undeclared.

Comment: I copied and pasted that exactly into the viewDidLoad and it came up with that error. I would think the string would be best because it is using the UITextField to add characters to the string, but then I would need to some how put the characters into the UITableViewCell

Comment: plz don't put this code in viewDidLoad. Put this code outside viewDidLoad because it is method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take one array for it and simply add your text in the array every time.  After adding your text in the array simply reload your tableview. use this array in the table view for displaying the text.